# Where to put third-party plugins/libraries in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, markitup

I'm using the [markItUp!](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) jQuery-based editor in an ASP.NET MVC project.  I understand the purpose of the various default folders in ASP.NET MVC, but I'm not sure how a third-party plugin like markItUp! fits into this structure.

markItUp! has its own images, CSS files, and scripts, but instead of separating those files into the existing project folders (Content, Scripts, etc.), I'd like to keep everything together.  There are 2 reasons for this:

1. Distinguishing between my own code
   and the code of the markItUp!
   library.
2. Upgrading to a new version of
   markItUp!

Should I create a new folder called "Libraries" (or "Plugins" or "ThirdParty") and place the top-level markItUp folder inside?  That way I could also add other third-party code as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I began to replace Content and Script folders with a folder structure similar to this:

- Public

  - Css
  - Scripts
  - Images
  - ...
  - fancybox
  - markitup

The reason why I put it all in a folder called "Public" is that in contrary to Views or Controller folder  there are only directly accessible files in it.

I think it makes sense to put third party pugins in its own folders. I do it without some "plugins" folder inside the Public folder mainly to get shorter urls.